# How do I deactivate a specific version of gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I have two versions of rack installed on my computer 1.0.1 and 1.2.1
However, when I tried to push my git to Heroku, it complains

```
     You have already activated rack 1.0.1, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.1. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

How can I deactivate rack 1.0.1 and activate 1.2.1 instead? (I can't uninstall 1.0.1 since it's under system folder and I don't have the root password)

```
   gem list -d rack

      *** LOCAL GEMS ***

      rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
      Author: Christian Neukirchen
      Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/rack
      Homepage: http://rack.rubyforge.org
      Installed at (1.2.1): /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
             (1.0.1): /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

     a modular Ruby webserver interface
```

And this is my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.1'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '0.1.0'
gem 'devise', '1.1.3'  
gem 'omniauth' 
gem 'fb_graph'
gem 'rack', '1.2.1'
gem 'annotate-models'
gem 'webrat'
gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the Aspen stack, and will need to switch to Bamboo to accomplish what you're trying to do.

http://docs.heroku.com/stack

Comment: This is what I got:   heroku stack
  aspen-mri-1.8.6
* bamboo-ree-1.8.7
  bamboo-mri-1.9.1 (beta)
  bamboo-mri-1.9.2 (beta)
so it looks like I am using Bamboo

Comment: Is rack referenced in your Gemfile twice or without a specific version? Posting your Gemfile might help.

Comment: The next thing I would rule out is that one of your gems is explicitly requiring rack 1.0.1. You can check this with gem dependency.

Comment: Most of them are like this: rack(>= 1.0.0,runtime), or  rack(>= 1.0.1,runtime) not sure if they will automatically choose 1.0.1.